# WinJS.UI.NavBar doesn't show (Microsoft.WinJS.1.0)

Tags: windows-8, winjs, navbar

I'm creating a navbar for my windows 8 application (visual studio 2012) and I can't make it work.
then I went back to the basics. I created an empty app and added this code in the body of the default.html:

```
<div id="navBar" class="global" 
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.NavBar">
    <div 
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.NavBarCommand" 
        data-win-options="{
        label:'Home',
        icon:'home',
        location: '/pages/home/home.html',
        tooltip: 'Return to home page'}">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contenthost">
    hi Maurizio
</div>
```

Shouldn't this be enough to see a nav bar when I right click with my mouse anywhere in the app?

I¨also tried adding some javascript in the nav.onnavigated event in default.js, but I don't think that has to do with the nav not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason.

The WinJS.UI.NavBar control is only available on Windows 8.1, it's part of WinJS 2.0 and is not available in WinJS 1.0 on Win8.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7557e9d7-5c63-49fa-9b19-d4640f089131/unable-to-create-a-nav-bar?forum=winappswithhtml5

Comment: That's correct. With the 8.1 documentation now on MSDN, it's important to check the version availability at the bottom of the reference topics to know if it's 8.0/WinJS 1.0 or 8.1/WinJS 2.0. For what it's worth, the WinRT references also indicate availability on Windows Phone 8.